# Minikube failed to start, unable to allocate 4000 MB

Tags: minikube

When I'm trying to start minikube I get the following error

> 'minikube' is unable to allocate 4000 MB of RAM:

and a proposed solution

> Failed to start hyperv VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it:

How should I continue?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try deleting the cluster (minikube delete) and then start it and pass it a memory flag (--memory 4000) to set it to use 4000 MB of memory.

As per the solution given by phydeauxman in the post [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60603173/19230181),  Minikube was attempting to create a VM with 4077 MB of memory which was causing the failure. When you run minikube setup with the command, initialization will be completed successfully:

1. `minikube delete`
2. `minikube start --driver=hyperv --memory=4000m`

With the help of the above commands you will delete the minikube cluster and start it again by passing it with a memory flag.